# Which of the following guarantee that the equation $x^n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}a_ix^i$ has at least one root in the interval $(0, 1)$?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $n$ be an integer greater than $1$. Which of the following guarantee that the equation $x^n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}a_ix^i$ has at least one root in the interval $(0, 1)$?
>
> (I) $a_0 > 0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i < 1$
>
> (II) $a_0 > 0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i > 1$
>
> (III) $a_0 < 0$ and $\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} a_i > 1$
>
> (a) None
>
> (b) I only
>
> (c) II only
>
> (d) III only
>
> (e) I and III only

I was thinking of using Lagrange's mean value theorem. If I could have some $F(0) = 0$ and $F(1) = 1$ then for some $c \in (0, 1)$ the value of $F'(c) = (F(1) - F(0))/(1-0)$. If we have $0 < \frac{F(1) - F(0)}{1 - 0} < 1$ we should be done and $F'(c) = f(c)$ would then lie in $(0, 1)$, where say $f(x) = x^n - \sum_{n-1}a_ix^i$.

Say, I construct $F(x)$ as $\frac{x^n}{n+1} - \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} a_i \frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}$. Then the required condition can be stated as

$$0 < \frac{F(1) - F(0)}{1 - 0} < 1$$
$$\implies 0 < \frac{1}{n+1} - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_i}{i+1} < 1$$

However, this does not seem to match with any of the stated options. Is my approach incorrect?

**Edit**: Oh, actually I just realized my condition just says that $f'(c)$ lies between $0$ and $1$ at some point $c$ in $(0, 1)$. Not that it has a root (vanishes, i.e., $f'(c) = 0$) for some $c$ in $(0, 1)$.

So is there some other approach for this problem? Would say Rolle's theorem be helpful?

If say, $F(1) = F(0)$ then that might be sufficient condition for $F'(c) = f(c)$ to vanish at some $c \in (0, 1)$. But even the condition we get from Rolle's theorem doesn't seem to match any of the options.

Comment: Did you try using the intermediate mean value theorem? If $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are of opposite signs for a continuous function $f$, then $f$ has atleast one root in the interval  $(0,1)$.

Comment: What about intermediate value theorem?

Comment: What about intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Let
$f(x)
=x^n - \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}a_ix^i
$.

Then
$f(0) = -a_0$
and
$f(1)
=1 - \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}a_i
$.

For $f$ to have a root
in $(0, 1)$,
it is sufficient if
$f(0)$ and $f(1)$
have opposite signs.

If $\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}a_i > 1$
then $f(1) < 0$,
and
if $\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}a_i < 1$
then $f(1) > 0$.

Also, $a_0 > 0$
implies $f(0) < 0$
and
$a_0 < 0$
implies $f(0) > 0$.

Now put these together.

Comment: what if there is more than one root ? say 2 how do we consider that condition too?then f(o)  and f(1) need not be of opposite sign

Comment: That's why I wrote sufficient.

Comment: Yeah i got it .+1

Answer (score 2):

For $$f(x)=x^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_kx^k$$ you have $f(0)=-a_0$ and $f(1)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k$.

So you have directly that number **(I)** and **(III)** are true, by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: And to prove that *(II)* does not guarantee a root in the interval $(0,1)$, consider the polynomial $x^2=4$, which meets criterion *(II)* but does not have any roots in the interval